# problem with grep using a pattern file

Tags: grep

I am experiencing the following problem (I have simplified it for the purpose of asking a question). I have a pattern file `patternfile.txt` as such, which is sorted:

```
ALNTPKDHI  
CTDDNALAY  
CTDDNALAYY
```

and a lookup file `lookup.txt`:

```
ALNTPKDHI 1  
CTDDNALAY 2  
CTDDNALAYY 3
```

I run the command:

```
$ grep -w -f patternfile.txt lookupfile.txt
```

and it returns this:

```
ALNTPKDHI 1  
CTDDNALAY 2
```

And the 3rd entry doesn't return a match, even though it should. I will note that if I swap the order of the last two entries in the `patternfile.txt`, it returns all 3.

Can anyone explain?

Thank you!

Comment: Does your `patternfile.txt` have any lines with spaces at the end?  The examples you have here do have trailing spaces.  If they do, that could cause the behavior you're seeing (and explain why I0b0 wasn't able to reproduce the problem with his experiment).

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce:

```
$ printf '%s\n' ALNTPKDHI CTDDNALAY CTDDNALAYY > patterns.txt
$ printf '%s\n' 'ALNTPKDHI 1' 'CTDDNALAY 2' 'CTDDNALAYY 3' > input.txt
$ grep -w -f patterns.txt input.txt 
ALNTPKDHI 1
CTDDNALAY 2
CTDDNALAYY 3
```

Please check whether the patterns or input contain any unusual control or whitespace characters such as carriage return.

Answer (score 1):

I can only reproduce what you are seeing if the pattern file's last line is incomplete, i.e. if the last line does not end with a terminating newline. When a line is incomplete, `grep` will not use that line.

If you run `od -c` on the file, you can see what the last character is.  This is an example of the last line *not* ending in a newline:

```
$ od -c pattern.txt
0000000    A   L   N   T   P   K   D   H   I  \n   C   T   D   D   N   A
0000020    L   A   Y  \n   C   T   D   D   N   A   L   A   Y
0000035
```

This is an example of what it may look like if the file ends in a newline character:

```
$ od -c pattern.txt
0000000    A   L   N   T   P   K   D   H   I  \n   C   T   D   D   N   A
0000020    L   A   Y  \n   C   T   D   D   N   A   L   A   Y  \n
0000036
```

You may add a newline to the file using

```
echo >>pattern.txt
```

Most text editors will automatically add a terminating newline character to the last line of a text when saving the file if there was none there originally.